# Calculating slope in degrees from a fitted line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have fitted a line using Scipy's `lineregress` on some data resulting in the following plot:

[image: Plot]

I'm trying to convert the slope to degrees and used the following method:

```
in_rads=np.arctan(res.slope)
degrees=np.degrees(in_rads)

print("Slope=",res.slope)
print("Slope in Radians=", in_rads)
print("Slope in degrees", degrees)
```

But I get the following result:

```
Slope= 0.00010043299346655021 
Slope in Radians= 0.00010043299312886817
Slope in degrees 0.005754386630150542
```

There is no way that slope is 0.00575 degrees.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a different scale for the x and y axis.  What you're getting is the actual slope if the axes were the same scale.  Multiply res.slope by 1000 to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: If the axes have not the same scale, then scope in meaningless. I mean, we don't know what x and y are. But, if they are not even the same units (which seems likely, from the discrepancy of their values; if it were the same units, and comparable, but with f crushing the x value severely, you would probably not have made this interpretation mistake), so, for example if x is a time and y a speed, then computing a slope in degrees make no sense at all.

Comment: So, unlike Frank Yellin, I wouldn't even thell "multiply by 1000" (that would be assuming that each markers on each axis are comparable. But I bet they are not. It just happens that matplotlib tends to choose the markers so that they have approximately a constant size. But, I don't feel that 1000 on x-axis have exactly the same size as 1 on y-axis. Just approximately so, thanks to auto-scaling and auto-choice of markers by matplotlib). So don't multiply by 1000. It wouldn't lead to a correct slope. Just to a slope that is as meaningless as the one you have, just less obviously so.

Comment: @chrisg.  You are correct.  My mistake.

Comment: @chrslg understood. The X axis is just a row number. But even it wasn’t. How do I rescale to get the units comparable to get a meaningful slope value?

Comment: If your X variable is not meaningful, you should fix that before you run the regression. Is there a way to relate the row number to a variable that is meaningful and that you care about?

Comment: If you can fix X not being meaningful, then `res.slope` is already meaningful. A slope of 0.0001 means that when your input variable increases by 1, then your output variable increases by 0.0001.

Comment: @NickODell to chrslg's comment, if the x axis is time and y axis is speed of a snail, the axes are meaningful, but then for every 1 min the snail moves only 0.01m which will still yield a very small slope. So actually, it seems that if the x-axis is meaningful, it's very difficult to calculate slope in degrees. But if the X axis is arbitrary, I can resample the X intervals to match the Y axis?

Comment: You could, but the slope would always be 45 degrees. (If slope = rise / run, and you make rise and run equal, then slope = 1, and arctan(1) = 45 degrees.) I also don't think that angle is a meaningful thing to calculate. In the case of the snail, angle has no clear geometric interpretation.

Comment: Thank you! That actually makes perfect sense! :)